# How to assert object values after update inside a void method - Junit

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I want to assert whether the value of the SalsGroupId in the `MyObject` has been changed after it invoke the `initMyObj`.

When I mock the `MyObject` I cannot assert the changed value because it return the same mock value. I understand that is Mockito behaviour. But how to test this?

```
@Component( "mybean" )
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope( value="session" )  
public class MyBean {

   @Autowired
   private MyObject myObj;

   public void initMyObj(String SalsGroupId){

     if (!SalsGroupId.equals(myObj.getSalsGroupId())) {

        getMyObj().setSalsGroupId(SalsGroupId);  // update the SalsGroupId
        getMyObj().setMyString("My STRING"); // initially this is null            

     }
   }

   public MyObject getMyObj(){
       return myObj;
   }
}
```

===== in Junit Test.

```
  @InjectMocks
private MyBean myBean;

@Mock
private MyObject myObj;

@Test
public void initInitMyObject() {  
when(myBean.getMyObj().getSalsGroupId()).thenReturn("SOME_STRING");

     myBean.initMyObj("OTHER");   

     assertEquals("OTHER",myBean.getMyObj().getSalsGroupId()); // but the value is still "SOME_STRING"

     assertEquals("My STRING",myBean.getMyObj().getMyString()); // but the value is null

}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code, to make sure you actually call the setter?

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, MyObj is not null. But the properties of it is null. Before and after the initMyObj()

Comment: I didn't ask whether myObj is null or not. Have you actually verified that !SalsGroupId.equals(myObj.getSalsGroupId()) returns true? Have you checked that the code in that if block is executed?

Comment: @Stultuske yes. It is going inside the if condition. No errors in the method. Yes I did debug it.

Comment: You should never ever mock a data object! Simply construct an instance and use it. Then things will make more sense!

Comment: @jokster it's autowired. myObj contains many other objects, which are autowired and no setter methods to set the instances.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use asserts here. Use Mockito.verify() to ensure that .setSalsGroupId() and .setMyString() methods are called with proper parameters:

```
@Test
public void initInitMyObject() {  
  when(myBean.getMyObj().getSalsGroupId()).thenReturn("SOME_STRING");

  myBean.initMyObj("OTHER");   

  verify(myBean.getMyObj()).setSalsGroupId(<expected value>);
  verify(myBean.getMyObj()).setMyString("My STRING");

}
```

Comment: Yay. This works. But is this how I should write test for this kind of situation? or is there another way to verify what is the object value? Just curious about other options.

Comment: @abinet you are just changing what has been tested. If you want to know whether the object is indeed what it has been changed to, yes, you need an assert

Comment: @Stultuske but how to assert then? any way to do it?

Comment: @everalian exactly the way you do it. I think your mock is wrong. you mock: myBean.getMyObject().getSalsgroupId() but you never execute that, you execute myObject.getSalsgroupId();

Comment: @Stultuske the mock is to go to pass the value to go through the if condition. What do you mean by not using myBean.getMyObject().getSalsgroupId() ?? I updated the mock object details in the initial question.